# How can i scale a svg text horizontal center?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this html code:

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: min(18vw, 200px);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

svg rect {
  fill: white;
  mask: url(#videomask);
}

svg > rect {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <video autoplay playsinline muted loop preload>
       <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    </video>
    <svg height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
        <defs>
            <mask id="videomask" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
                <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">svg mask</text>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    </svg>
</section>
```

My goal is to enlarge the SVG text to such an extent that you only see the video at the end (zoom effect). I've already tried to increase the `font-size`, but then the text is no longer horizontally centered during scaling, which doesn't look nice.

[image]

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: As it's written, the desired result seems to be not very clear. Could you please elaborate more on when you need to enlarge the text (hover, click etc) and its start and final states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your code and it may not be what you want. For the svg I'm using a `viewBox = "-320 -180 640 360"` where the width/height raport ratio is the same as the raport ratio of the video.

Also in your code you are masking all the rects of the svg element. I'm masking only the last one.

I'm scaling this last rect using a SMIL animation. You can use CSS here.

I hope it helps.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  width:100%;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

svg rect {
  fill: white;
}

svg > rect {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay playsinline muted loop preload>
       <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    </video> 
<svg viewBox = "-320 -180 640 360">
        <defs>
            <mask id="videomask">

                <rect x="-320" y="-180" height="100%" width="100%"/>
                <text id="elText" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="100" >svg mask</text> 
            </mask>
        </defs>
  <rect x="-320" y="-180" height="100%" width="100%" mask="url(#videomask)">
     <animateTransform  
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="scale"
        values="1,1;500,500" 
        attributeType="XML"
        dur="25s"
        begin="3s"          
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="1"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```